# Can I switch my application pool from .NET 2 to .NET 4 without danger?

Tags: .net, iis

I have screwturn installed it uses app pool .net 2. Can I switch to .NET 4 without danger ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should help: [How to: Upgrade an ASP.NET Web Application to ASP.NET 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd483478.aspx).  You shouldn't have any issues.  Personally I'd try it in a local or test environment first.

Comment: Never ever do this directly into production. There are breaking changes between .NET 2.0 and 4.0.

Comment: Well I try to change the app pool and screwturn doesn't work any more happily I could revert :). So yeah seems I need to upgrade with VS

Answer (score 3):

No, basically. When I last changed from 2.0 to 4.0 on an app-pool, we needed subtle but critical changes to configuration files (in particular), but ultimately ***any*** part of the runtime could have feature changes that break existing code on some edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for Screwturn wiki, per developer Dario Solera (Jan 2012): [You must run STW in a .NET 2.0 app pool as .NET 4.0 is not supported.](http://www.screwturn.eu/forum/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=9793#p23182)